# How can I provide demo data with my app without backing it up to iCloud?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icloud, data-storage

I have an app in the App Store since January, that copies a database file to the "Documents" directory at first launch.

This database is used to store "presets", created by users. Each preset can have up to 129 photos.

At start, the app comes with a "default preset", that users can use to understand and start to use the app. This preset is like a "gift" to the user, and if he doesn't want it anymore, he can just delete it.

On update 2.0.2 nothing was changed in this schema, but Apple rejected my update now.

> 2.23 - Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will
>   be rejected

I can't figure out how I can solve this. The issue seems to be that the default preset, which Apple considers "temporary" gets backed up to iCloud. This preset is NOT temporary. It must persist, and is part of the database.

I also can't mark the database with the "do not back up", because this way the "presets" created by the users won't be backed up, which would be terrible.

Anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flag the file to [not backup to iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html).

Without flagging the file as such, it will be eligible to backup to iCloud. Apple has recently began to enforce this.

If the app generates a lot of data, on app startup, they'll reject it. Apple's reasoning  for this is that **any data that can be regenerated** should not be backed up to iCloud.

To prevent this, Apple recommends:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Other than that blanket omission from iCloud, the only thing you're left with is separating your *user generated* content from your *re-creatable content*.

Comment: My problem is this initial content is on the same database that user's content. All photos are stored in database. This is a update, so I can't separate this now, or flag the entire database.

Comment: Is that all that's in the database? User content?

Comment: Unfortunatelly yes. All pictures are stored on database, that already have the "default preset" when is copied at first launch.

Comment: Given the unique requirements, I'd contact Apple's support. Clearly their policy doesn't work with your requirements. Not saying they'll budge, but it couldn't hurt.

Comment: Another thought, though risky, that crosses my mind is to initially exclude the DB from iCloud and LATER (after 4 minutes of app usage, etc) remove the flag. Surely their testers won't notice the switch ;-) YMMV.

Comment: Well .. and if I add an option in the app settings, where the user can enable or disable the "Backup" option (off by default)?

Comment: Let me know how it works. I'll also not turn down an up-vote ;-)

Comment: After a long wait, my update has been finally approved! The solution leaving the backup disabled by default with an internal option worked! Thank you for opening my mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

"do not back up" is a file-level attribute. So perhaps mark only your "gift" files with that attribute?

Comment: Because it is a update, and all files are stored on the same database, the "gift" and the user's content are in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the guidelines are pretty clear on this -- only **user generated data** may be stored in the Documents directory and backed up to iCloud.

However, it looks like you can prevent specific files from being backed up:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342

You are going to have to find a way to separate your preset data from the user's data store and mark the preset data as "do not back up"

Answer (score 0):

I faced that same problem with one of my apps. I had to generate another version of my database and store it into the Caches folder, and mark it as not eligible for iCloud backup. Then store all user generated content into another database in the documents folder, which actually gets backed up to iCloud.